# Examples of continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

What are some nice examples of continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where the images of open sets are not open, and the images of closed sets are not closed?

Comment: By the way, if $f$ is continuous, then $f([a,b])$ is always closed. That is, the continuous image of a closed _and bounded_ interval is always closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any constant function would do for the first; or, if you prefer, periodic functions like $\sin$ or $\cos$.

For the second, since $\mathbb{R}$ is closed, a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-1,1)$ (e.g., $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan$) would do.

Answer (score 3):

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous. $(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ but $f((-1,1))=[0,1)$ is NOT open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Or you could let $f(x)=\frac{x^4}{x^2+1},$ which *I think* gives a function that need not map closed sets to closed sets either.

Comment: @CameronBuie Are you sure? The graph of $\frac{x^4}{x^2+1}$ is just a misshapen parabola. What closed set are you thinking of?

Comment: Oops! That $x^4$ was supposed to be $x^2.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\Bbb R$ is open *and* closed. Let:
$$f(x)=\frac1{x^2+1}$$
Now, $f(\Bbb R)=(0,1]$ is neither open nor closed. (I suggest you graph $f$.)